# Viewing all Products that a Customer has purchased on Stripe

Tags: python-3.x, stripe-payments

How can I view all `Products` that a `Customer` has purchased using the Stripe API? Is there a specific event that is sent out when a purchase occurs? I'm seeing that there is an `Orders` item as well, but am not sure that `Products` can only be purchased as part of `Orders`.

Sample query for getting all Orders by a Customer:

```
from stripe import Order

Order.list(customer=customer_1['data'][0].id)
```

Basically I want to get all non-subscription-based items that the user has purchased -- will querying the API for Orders this way give me all non-subscription-based items, since a `Product` must necessarily each be tied to an `Order`, or is there a different/better way of doing this?

Answer (score -1):

You can retrieve all orders for a customer with the [list all orders](https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_orders) method and the `customer` parameter.

You can then go through the order's [`items`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#order_object-items) attribute to find the SKUs included in the order.

Finally, you can use a SKU's [`product`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#sku_object-product) attribute to retrieve the product associated to the SKU.

In Python, you could do something like this:

```
customer_id = "cus_..."
products = []  # list of products ordered at least once by the customer

orders = stripe.Order.list(customer=customer_id)
for order in orders.auto_paging_iter():
    for item in order.items.auto_paging_iter():
        if item.type == "sku":
            sku = stripe.SKU.retrieve(item.parent)
            if sku.product not in products:
                products.append(product)
```

The above code is not very efficient as it would send a [SKU retrieve request](https://stripe.com/docs/api#retrieve_sku) for every item of type `"sku"`. In practice, you'd likely want to cache the results and only retrieve each SKU once.

Comment: Thanks! Will every instance of a `Product` being purchased necessarily be attached to an `Order`, though? i.e. is it possible for businesses to charge clients for a `Product` (or some other abstraction for a non-subscription-based purchase) without an `Order` being placed?